# Why is $2x^3 + x$, where $x \in \mathbb{N}$, always divisible by 3?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

So, do you guys have any ideas? Sorry if this might seem like dumb question, but I have asked everyone I know and we haven't got a clue.

Comment: This isn't true.

Comment: Are you sure your problem statement is correct?  I ask because if $x=2$, then $2x^2+x = 10$ which isn't divisible by 3.

Comment: Did you mean $2x^3+x$?

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen : I took the liberty to edit , now the solution is simple by Fermatt's little theorem.

Comment: You are violating asker's rights

Comment: @DonAnselmo: My apologies (though the question "now" has a positive score)

Comment: I might word it differently, but I certainly agree with @DonAnselmo.

Comment: I agree with Don Anselmo. That edit changed the question quite a bit (even though it turned it into a better question). But the misprint might have been something else, or it may have been a genuine mistake. Such a change should be at least ok'd by the OP before implementing it :-(

Comment: apologize to the asker. Not to us

Answer (score 12):

This should be clear: $2x^3+x\equiv x-x^3(\mod 3)\equiv -x(x-1)(x+1)(\mod 3)\equiv 0$.

Answer (score 4):

certainly true for $n = 1$. IF $2n^3 + n \cong_3 0 $, then
$$ 2(n + 1)^3 + n + 1 = 2(n^3 + 3n^2 + 3n + 1) + n + 1 = 2n^3 +6n^2 + 6n +2 + n + 1 $$

$$ = (2n^3 + n ) + 3(2n^2 + 2n + 1) \cong_3 0$$

REsult follows from math induction.

Answer (score 4):

“Fermat's little theorem” says that, if $p$ is a prime, then $a^p\equiv a\pmod{p}$, for all integers $a$.

Then
$$
2x^3+x\equiv2x+x\equiv3x\equiv0\pmod{3}
$$

Comment: +1 because it's a deeper (and more general) explanation for the equality than just multiplying it out. But it's missing an accessible proof of Fermat's little theorem...

Comment: @alexis http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_little_theorem

Comment: It wasn't for my benefit, but thanks. (I've always liked the group theory proof myself, but maybe the "proofs using modular arithmetic" would be more a propos here.)

Answer (score 3):

$2x^3+x=x\cdot(2x^2+1)$. If $3|x$, then the result follows immediately. Otherwise, $x=3k\pm1\rightarrow$ $\iff2(3k\pm1)^2+1=2(9k^2\pm6k+1)+1=18k^2\pm12k+3=3(6k^2\pm4k+1)$. QED.

Answer (score 3):

$2x^3+x=3x^3-x(x-1)(x+1)$; since $x-1,x,x+1$ are three consecutive integers, one of them is divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 2):

$x \mod 3=\{0,1,2\}$ for $x\in \mathbb{N}$.

In the other words, if you divide any natural number by $3$, the remainder will be $0$ or $1$ or $2$.

- $x \mod 3=0 \Rightarrow (2x^3 + x) \mod 3 = 0$
- $x \mod 3=1 \Rightarrow (2x^3 + x) \mod 3 = 0$
- $x \mod 3=2 \Rightarrow (2x^3 + x) \mod 3 = 0$

Answer (score 2):

2x<sup>3</sup> + x = x(2x<sup>2</sup> + 1) = x(2x<sup>2</sup> - 2 + 3) = x[2(x + 1)(x - 1) + 3] = 3x + 2x(x + 1)(x - 1)

3x is always divisible by 3 and one of x - 1, x, x + 1 is also always divisble by 3

Answer (score 1):

By the Fermat's little theorem,

$$x^3 \equiv x \pmod 3$$

, therefore

$$2x^3 + x \equiv 2x + x \equiv 3x \equiv 0 \pmod 3$$